# Inserting Dynamic Form inputs into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

**index.php**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldGroup">
             <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" name="winner_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Name" required />
                    <input type="text" name="winner_card[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Card No." required />
                    <input type="text" name="winner_prize[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Prize" required />
                    <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger">*</a>
                     </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="addWinner" />
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="col-2 offset-1 btn btn-warning addMore">+</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="col-7 offset-1 btn btn-lg btn-warning" id="acwB">Add Winners </button>
                    </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                </form>

                    <div class="fieldGroupCopy d-none">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="winner_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Name" required/>
                            <input type="text" name="winner_card[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Card No." required/>
                            <input type="text" name="winner_prize[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Prize" required/>
                            <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<script>
        var max_fields = 20;
    $(".addMore").click(function(){
        if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < max_fields){
            var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
            $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
        }else{
            alert('Maximum '+max_fields+' inputs are allowed.');
        }
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
    });
$("#wnrForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            url: "w_insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data) {
                if(data == 1) {
                    $('#wnrForm').trigger("reset");
                    $('.remove').parents('.fieldGroup').remove();
                alert('inserted');
            } else {
                alert('Error');
            }

            }          
          });
          }));
</script>
```

**w_insert.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['addWinner'])) {
    $w_name= $_POST['winner_name'];
    $w_card = $_POST['winner_card'];
    $w_prize = $_POST['winner_prize'];

    for ($i = 0; $i<count($w_name); $i++) {
        if($w_name[i]!="") {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO winners (w_name, w_card , w_prize) VALUES ('$w_name[$i]', '$w_card[$i]', '$w_prize[$i]')";
            $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

**table winners**

| id | w_name | w_card | w_prize |

I want to insert dynamic fields data from HTML form into MySQL table i can able add multiple fields in html form and also able to send to w_insert.php file but there i am getting 3 different arrays ive tried for loop but its not working in my case. i want w_name , w_card , w_prize to be insert respectively in mysql table

Comment: what is $wn in your code?

Comment: $wn is $w_name i have typo there i have corrected it now thanks for pointing out

Comment: it should be $w_name[$i]

Comment: form is not complete, you just included the closing tag</form> and 2nd set of input in outside form please rectify it asap

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using FormData. to use this you have to define form tag then you will be use formdata to get all input value. so you should create you code.
i have done correction in your code that will work fine and pass value to w_insert.php viw ajax.

```html
     <form action="#" id="myForm">
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldGroup">
             <div class="input-group">
             
                   <input type="text" name="winner_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Name" required />
                    <input type="text" name="winner_card[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Card No." required />
                    <input type="text" name="winner_prize[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Prize" required />
                    <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger">*</a>
                     </div>
                   </div>
           </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="addWinner" />
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="col-2 offset-1 btn btn-warning addMore">+</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="col-7 offset-1 btn btn-lg btn-warning" id="wnrForm">Add Winners </button>
                    
                    </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                </form>

                    <div class="fieldGroupCopy d-none">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="winner_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Name" required/>
                            <input type="text" name="winner_card[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Card No." required/>
                            <input type="text" name="winner_prize[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Winner Prize" required/>
                            <div class="input-group-addon"> 
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">  
 </script>  
<script>
        var max_fields = 20;
    $(".addMore").click(function(){
        if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < max_fields){
            var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
            $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
        }else{
            alert('Maximum '+max_fields+' inputs are allowed.');
        }
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
    });
$("#wnrForm").on('click',(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
          let form = new FormData(myForm);
          console.log(form);
          $.ajax({
            url: "w_insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  form,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data) {
                if(data == 1) {
                    document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
                    $('.remove').parents('.fieldGroup').remove();
                alert('inserted');
            } else {
                alert('Error');
            }

            }          
          });
          }));
</script>
```